# In Perl, how do I get the directory or path of the current executing code?

Tags: perl

If I am in some library code, how do I determine the path to the file of the code that is currently executing?  I know how to get the path of the *top* perl file by looking at `ARGV`, but if I load a library, how can that *library* know which path it is at?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `__FILE__` token will give you the full path including the file name. You can use [File::Spec](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html) to split it into components:

```
my ($volume, $directory, $file) = File::Spec->splitpath(__FILE__);
```

Comment: I think this will not handle relative paths properly.

Comment: @Leon: That depends on what you mean by "properly." The value of `__FILE__` should match what you'd get from `%INC`. If you've added relative paths to `@INC` then you might get relative file paths back. `splitpath()` will handle that but the directory portion will be relative instead of absolute. You can use `File::Spec->rel2abs()` to convert a (possibly) relative path to an absolute one if that's a concern.

Comment: Of course, `__FILE__` might not actually be the file.  Try running `warn __FILE__` after saying `#line 42 foo.bar` somewhere in the file.

Comment: Did anyone actually try this? I get only the name of the script, not the full path. Furthermore, I've searched the Internet for '\_\_FILE\_\_' and all the documentation I see says that's exactly what I should get!!!

Comment: Works like a charm.

Comment: For me, using "Win32 strawberry-perl 5.30.2.1" `__FILE__` also does not (always?) return the full path, but the name of the script as provided to the perl binary. So when starting "perl ./myscript.pl" `__FILE__` returns "./myscript.pl"...

Answer (score 15):

The easiest way to find the **filename of the current executable** is with [FindBin](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/FindBin):

```
use FindBin;
use File::Spec;

print "the directory of my script is: " . $FindBin::Bin . "\n";
print "the base name of my script is: " . $FindBin::Script . "\n";
print "the canonical location of my script is: " . File::Spec->catfile($FindBin::Bin, $FindBin::Script) . "\n";
```

Internally, you can get at some of this information by looking at `$0` (the name of the script as invoked at the command line), and `__FILE__`, which is the name of the currently-executing file.  (See [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).)

To extract the **filename of the currently-executing module**, start with examining `__PACKAGE__`, do some substitution magic and then look up the filename in `%INC`:

```
(my $filename = __PACKAGE__ ) =~ s#::#/#g;
$filename .= '.pm';
my $abs_filename = $INC{$filename};
```

I do this in one of my initialization libraries to find a configuration script in a path relative to the current module (I have several code branches installed side-by-side, each with slightly different configs):

```
# use the location of the current module as a guide for where to find configs
(my $filename = __PACKAGE__ ) =~ s#::#/#g;
$filename .= '.pm';

(my $path = $INC{$filename}) =~ s#/\Q$filename\E$##g; # strip / and filename
my $abs_config_file = File::Spec->catfile($path, $config_file);
MyApp->initialize($abs_config_file);
```

Comment: that will give him the name of the script executed form the commandline (I think) not the name of the "library module" being executed.

Comment: @lexu: I added that bit in the next paragraph (just after you left that comment) :)

Comment: right you are, good answer, but a bit more complex than _ _ FILE _ _

Comment: You mention both `__FILE__` and a solution using `%INC`. Is there a reason to avoid the simpler `__FILE__` variable and use the `%INC` solution instead?

Answer (score 1):

Any libraries included via `use` or `require` produce an entry in the special `%INC` hash. (See [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)).

For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper \%INC;
```

This will produce output similar to the following:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'warnings/register.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/warnings/register.pm',
      'bytes.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/bytes.pm',
      'XSLoader.pm' => '/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/XSLoader.pm',
      'Carp.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Carp.pm',
      'Exporter.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Exporter.pm',
      'strict.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/strict.pm',
      'warnings.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/warnings.pm',
      'overload.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/overload.pm',
      'Data/Dumper.pm' => '/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Data/Dumper.pm'
    };
```

Additionally, there is a universal `__FILE__` constant which will return the current filename. (See also `__PACKAGE__`).

Answer (score 1):

This is the snippet I usually use to get the path for the executing code.

```
use Cwd qw/abs_path/;
my ($real_path) = abs_path($0) =~ m/(.*)myscript.pl/i;
```

This puts the actual directory path into $real_path.  I usually also perform `chdir $real_path` after this to make sure my code is actually working out of the directory it should be (usually when I'm writing a Windows service using Win32::Daemon).

The `abs_path` subroutine I've exported gives the path to whatever file (name/handle) you supply as the argument.  In this case I've supplied `$0` which is the name of the Perl script being executed.

I would recommend checking out [Cwd](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Cwd) on Cpan for a little more guidance.

Comment: slightly more generic way of writing the same thing: 
use Cwd qw/abs_path/;
( my $script_path = abs_path($0) ) =~ s|^(.*)([\/\\])(.*)|$1$2|g ;

Answer (score -4):

Easiest way:

```
print $ENV{'PWD'};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work.  If I am executing `/foo/bar/baz` from `/home/luser`, then `$ENV{PWD}` will return `/home/luser/` instead of `/foo/bar`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your answer may, or may not, be correct, but either way, we try to encourage people to explain their answer, not just post code snippets.

Comment: PWD it is bash (maybe other shells) env autoset variable. when some process change directory and calls your script then PWD points to previous directory, not current. better remove this answer preventing loosing points :)