# How can I capture the complete commandline in Perl?

Tags: perl, command-line

Suppose the call was

```
/usr/local/bin/perl verify.pl 1 3 de# > result.log
```

Inside `verify.pl` I want to capture the whole call above and append it to a log file for tracking purposes.

How can I capture the whole call as it is?

Answer (score 10):

`$0` has the script name and `@ARGV` has the arguments, so the whole commandline is:

`$commandline = $0 . " ". (join " ", @ARGV);`

or, more elegantly (thanks [FMc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55857/fmc)):

`$commandline = join " ", $0, @ARGV;`

I don't however, know how to capture the redirection (`> result.log`)

Comment: `$commandline = $0 . " " . (join " ", @ARGV);` to get a space between the scriptname and the first parameter, but that is just stupid detail

Comment: I don't think you can, since the shell just `dup`s the file descriptor for STDOUT to point to that log file. Perl has no way of knowing whether this has happened, as far as I can tell. (You MIGHT be able to detect whether an input redirection has happened by using `-t` though.)

Comment: @Fredrik: Hardly just a stupid detail-- if the user tries to run that command, the name of the script has essentially changed! :-)

Comment: FWIW, `join` takes multiple arguments:  `join(" ", $0, @ARGV)`.

Comment: Is there a way to capture /usr/local/bin/perl?

Comment: Is there any reason that `/usr/local/bin/perl` should be different than what is given by `which perl`?

Comment: Use Probe::Perl to find which Perl was actually used if there are multiple ones installed. A lot of server systems do have several Perls installed, to keep the system Perl intact for sysadmin while allowing other Perls to be updated and upgraded, integrated with Apache, etc.

Comment: The path to the perl executable can be accessed at runtime with `$^X` or with `$Config{perlpath}` (if you have loaded the `Config` module). `$Config{perlpath}` is preferable in some cases because it is a read-only variable.

Comment: There is no way to capture redirection. It's managed by the shell, i.e. the shell (bash, sh, cmd -- whatever) will open the file(s) and then run the command without `>`'s. However, one can guess whether certain file handle is a terminal, a file, or a pipe.

Comment: @Fredrik: you may have multiple versions of perl installed.  `which perl` will return the first one on the path.  Try `where perl` to see if you have any others on the path.

Comment: Note that ``@ARGV`` gets consumed by ``GetOptions()`` so you need to do this before.

Answer (score 10):

There is way (at least on unix-systems) to get whole command line:

```
my $cmdline = `ps -o args -C perl | grep verify.pl`;
print $cmdline, "\n";
```

e: Cleaner way using PID (courtesy of Nathan Fellman):

```
print qx/ps -o args $$/;
```

Comment: That's good, unless you have more than one instance of perl running.  You can filter that out with `getpid()`

Comment: @Nathan Fellman: Yes, there may be some issues to get the right one from processes, but i think OP can decide himself, how to properly filter specific process. By PID or by some grep pattern or ...

Comment: I was thinking of using something like `print qx/ps -o args $$/;`

Comment: well, why don't you edit your answer and get some more upvotes? :-)

Comment: By the way, does this also print the output redirection?

Comment: No, it does not. I am surprised. I thought it will.

Comment: This doesn't appear to maintain the shell quoting that was used on the command line, which may be a problem depending on what the original command line is needed for.

Comment: If you add an equal sign (=) after args you won't have the header line either. `print qx/ps -o args= $$/`

Answer (score 2):

`$commandline = join " ", $0, @ARGV;` does not handle the case that command line has quotes such as `./xxx.pl --love "dad and mom"`

A Quick Solution:

```
my $script_command = $0;
foreach (@ARGV) {
$script_command .= /\s/ ?   " \'" . $_ . "\'"
                :           " "   . $_;
}
```

Try to save the following code as `xxx.pl` and run `./xxx.pl --love "dad and mom"`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -w
use strict;
use feature qw ( say );
say "A: " . join( " ", $0, @ARGV );
my $script_command = $0;
foreach (@ARGV) {
    $script_command .= /\s/ ?   " \'" . $_ . "\'"
                    :           " "   . $_;
}
say "B: " . $script_command;
```

Comment: This is amazing. This is exactly i am looking for. Can you explain to me how this works? not sure what you are doing here

Answer (score 1):

Here virtually same Linux-only variants (of course, after shell intervention):

pure perl

```
BEGIN {
    my @cmd = ( );
    if (open(my $h, "<:raw", "/proc/$$/cmdline")) {
        # precisely, buffer size must be at least `getconf ARG_MAX`
        read($h, my $buf, 1048576); close($h);
        @cmd = split(/\0/s, $buf);
    };
    print join("\n\t", @cmd), "\n";
};
```

using File::Slurp:

```
BEGIN {
    use File::Slurp;
    my @cmd = split(/\0/s, File::Slurp::read_file("/proc/$$/cmdline", {binmode => ":raw"}));
    print join("\n\t", @cmd), "\n";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

See [In Perl, how do I get the directory or path of the current executing code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403343/in-perl-how-do-i-get-the-directory-or-path-of-the-current-executing-code)

Answer (score -1):

Example which handles more special cases (and without adding own name) and with processing the line with GetOpt:

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptionsFromString);
use feature qw ( say );

# Note: $0 is own name

my $sScriptCommandLine;
my @asArgs = ();

my $iRet;

my $sFile = '';
my $iN = -1;
my $iVerbose = 0;

# ============================================================================
my %OptionsHash = (
    "f=s"               => \$sFile,
    "n=i"               => \$iN,
    "v:+"               => \$iVerbose);



$sScriptCommandLine = join( ' ', @ARGV );  # useless for argument with spaces
say 'A: ' . $sScriptCommandLine;

$sScriptCommandLine = '"' . join( '" "', @ARGV ) . '"'; # all arguments in "", but not suitable for arguments with '"' (given as '\"')
say 'B: ' . $sScriptCommandLine;

$sScriptCommandLine = '';
foreach (@ARGV) {
  $sScriptCommandLine .= ' ' if ($sScriptCommandLine);
  $_ =~ s/\\/\\\\/g; # needed for GetOptionsFromString
  $_ =~ s/\"/\\\"/g;
  if (/\s/) {
    $sScriptCommandLine .= '"'.$_.'"';
  }
  else {
    $sScriptCommandLine .= $_;
  }
}
say 'C: ' . $sScriptCommandLine;


my ($iRet,$paArgs);
($iRet,$paArgs) = GetOptionsFromString($sScriptCommandLine,%OptionsHash);
# remaining parameters in $$paArgs[0] etc. 
if (!$iRet) {
  # error message already printed from GetOptionsFromString
  print "Invalid parameter(s) in: \"$sScriptCommandLine\"\n";
}

say 'D: ' . '<<' . join( '>>  <<', @{$paArgs} ) . '>>';
say 'f=s: "'.$sFile.'"'; 
say 'n=i: '.$iN; 
say 'v:+: '.$iVerbose; 

# eof
```