# In Perl,is there a keyword that means the directory that the current source file is in?

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Perl, how do I get the directory or path of the current executing code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403343/in-perl-how-do-i-get-the-directory-or-path-of-the-current-executing-code)

Not the current working directory,but the directory that the source being interpreted is in.

In **PHP** it's the `__DIR__` keyword, is there such a thing in **Perl**?

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=47035

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: that links to the more applicable http://perlmonks.org/?node=47035

Comment: No one has gien the correct answer.  The correct answer is `use File::Findbin qw($Bin)`.  The directory your script was installed in is now in `$Bin`.  It is possible to spoof this with serious intend, but it will work for most scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different sources for this.  You can try $ENV{PWD}, or use the Cwd module:

```
use Cwd;
my $cwd = getcwd;
```

Comment: Current working directory is different from the source file directory.

Comment: Especially in mod_perl.So this answer is INCORRECT.